# Fill UILabel content with device camera output

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uilabel, avcapturesession

I'm displaying a video output from device camera using `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`.
I would like to have an `UILabel` and to fill its content with camera output, just like in the picture below:
[image]

I can't find something useful to achieve this, does someone know how to do this effect?

Comment: I would try to mask the video layer with the labels layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
CATextLayer *label = [CATextLayer layer];
label.frame = self.cameraParentView.bounds;
label.foregroundColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
label.string = @"074";
label.font = (__bridge CFTypeRef)(@"Helvetica");
label.fontSize = 90;
label.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter;
label.wrapped = true;
label.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
self.cameraLayer.layer.mask = label;
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm.